# How can i get ng-change event in angular-ui-switch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular-ui-switch (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-switch)  as a toggle button.
I'm wondering that how can i get change event on the switch.

Comment: you can watch switch model in your controller.

Comment: @dhavalcengg I have written the following code to watch model. can you tell me what's wrong with this code?                          $scope.$watch('enabled_1', function() {
        alert('on');
    }, true);

Comment: Can you provide extract of your html and .js code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider following is your key

```
<switch id="enabled" name="enabled" ng-model="enabled" class="green"></switch>
```

You can have your watch something like this

```
$scope.$watch('enabled', function (newVal) {
 console.log('switch enabled : ' + newVal);
});
```